# count occurrences of a key in JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to count number of "items" in my json result for me to loop on it. Please see the code below which doesn't work for me:

```
var jsonResult:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
for var i = 0; i < jsonResult["items"].count; i++ {}
```

It gives me following compile error: 
"AnyObject? doesnt have a member named count"

Can you please help me understand the reason behind it? and also, 
Can you please let me know the work around it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not using SwiftyJSON?

Comment: Well I am new to whole ios programming and trying to learn as you can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `jsonResult["items"]` this return`AnyObject?` ,you have to convert it to real class it is.For example

```
 var dic:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dic.setValue(["first","second","third"], forKey: "items")
    var json:NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dic, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)!
    var jsondic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    var jsonItems = jsondic["items"] as NSArray
    for var i = 0;i < jsonItems.count; i++ {
        println(jsonItems[i] as String)
    }
```

This is the key

```
        var jsonItems = jsondic["items"] as NSArray
```

You may use "as?",so that if convert fail,you app will not crash

```
  var jsonItems = jsondic["items"] as? NSArray
        if(jsonItems != nil){
            for var i = 0;i < jsonItems!.count; i++ {
                println(jsonItems![i] as String)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're parsing dynamic data, the compiler can't make guarantees about what the JSON parser returns at runtime. For that reason, any value you retrieve from a JSON object is an optional you have to explicitly unwrap.

You can read about it at http://www.atimi.com/simple-json-parsing-swift-2/.

I believe there are libraries for JSON parsing in Swift now, that make this type of stuff a lot easier.

Comment: I came across this link which I thought was little advance for me but thanks for your reply and sharing.